# Integrate kafka Consumer spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka Consumer developed in spring-boot and i am able to read the messages from the topic.
I want to integrate it with the Spring batch because i want to create an batch file.
I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Batch added support to read/write data from/to Kafka topics in [v4.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewKafka), see [KafkaItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html) and [KafkaItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemWriter.html).

You can also take a look at the [Spring Tips installment](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/15/spring-tips-spring-batch-and-apache-kafka) about Kafka support in Spring Batch by Josh Long.

Comment: Can i use KafkaItemReader for consuming avro messages from the topic in my spring batch application?

Comment: yes, you can do that by setting the `key.deserializer` property to `KafkaAvroDeserializer` in the `consumerProperties` when creating the reader.

Comment: KafkaItemReader class will return records as GenericRecord? and i need to convert them to SpecificRecord or how it can be done?  Actually, i want to read the schema fields in which messages are coming and have to map all the fields to a java object and then create a batch file with the incoming data in a specified format.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine is there any support with spring batch with spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka. Because I have received kafka as stream. Then I need to pass those stream to spring batch. Is there any possibility ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I am following This way to read kafka stream from azure event hub. https://seroter.com/2018/05/29/how-to-use-the-kafka-interface-of-azure-event-hubs-with-spring-cloud-stream/

Answer (score 0):

Try like as below:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);
@KafkaListener(id = "batch-listener", topics = "${app.topic.batch}")
public void receive(@Payload List<String> messages,
                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {

    LOG.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
    LOG.info("beginning to consume batch messages");

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {

        LOG.info("received message='{}' with partition-offset='{}'",
                messages.get(i), partitions.get(i) + "-" + offsets.get(i));

    }
    LOG.info("all batch messages consumed");
}



 @EnableKafka
 @Configuration
 public class ListenerConfig {

@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "5");
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}

}
```

ref: https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-batch-listener-example/

Comment: How would i create a batch file out of it in some particular format with defined index for all the fields. Also, Do we need to care if the Producer is sending messages individually or in batches.

Comment: @Sonia which kind of file you need , not able to understand

and if you want to produce message in batch then u need to take care of that also.